Auto applying element styles
Im set style in App.xaml
<Style x:Key="ContentPageStyle" TargetType="ContentPage"> 
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=#FFFFFF, Dark=#020202}" />
</Style>

This style applying only case if set Style property for ContentPage element
<views:BasicView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SkeletonApp.View.Page;assembly=SkeletonApp"
                x:Class="SkeletonApp.Example.MainPage"
                Style="{StaticResource ContentPageStyle}"
                Title="Home">
                <!-- Content markup -->
</views:BasicView>

How can i do auto-applying styles when i set TargetType? It's truly possible?
And why style doesn't apply if i set Style property in parent class by next code
CS-file:
namespace SkeletonApp.View.Page
{
    public partial class BasicView : ContentPage
    {
        public BasicView() { }
    }
}

Markup-file:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SkeletonApp.View.Page.BasicView"
             Style="{StaticResource ContentPageStyle}">
</ContentPage>

UPD (full file App.xaml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="SkeletonApp.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="TransparentColor">Transparent</Color>

        <!-- Light colors -->
        <Color x:Key="LightPageBackgroundColor">Magenta</Color>

        <!-- Dark colors -->
        <Color x:Key="DarkPageBackgroundColor">Lime</Color>

        <Style x:Key="ContentPageStyle" TargetType="ContentPage"  ApplyToDerivedTypes = "True"> 
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                    Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPageBackgroundColor}}" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>


UPD v2: solution in other question

Following code in App.xaml works for me:
   <Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Lime" />
   </Style>

Note:

You should NOT use attribute x:Key in Style.
You should add ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"

I found solution at https://putridparrot.com/blog/styles-in-xamarin-forms/


You can just use ApplyToDerivedTypes = "True" in the App.Xaml and remove the Key to do that:
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes = "True"> 
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=#FFFFFF, Dark=#020202}"" />
</Style>


i tried to use this option ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" but its doesnt work(in my case) - auto-applying dont work.
u say about Styles.xaml - i dont found info about this file for root project, could u please attach some link with some info this file?

mb i dont right understanding about styles for Xamarin.Form - im upd my post: added full listing for App.xaml. Is not right way for set styles?

Sorry for my careless, I misunderstood your project as maui  project instead of xamarin project and I have updated the answer. @DarkVss
